# Sending form value using ajax, jquery,php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and jQuery. I am trying get html form value using ajax and jQuery. I am getting the value but i can not pass that value to another php file. I don't know what  i am missing.. can someone help me please..

Here is my form.php file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                var srt = $("#input").serialize();
                // alert is working perfect
                alert(srt);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'database.php',
                    data: srt,
                    success: function(d) {
                        $("#someElement").html(d);
                    }
            });
         });
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="input" method="post" action="">
    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit " name="submit">
</form>
<div id="someElement"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is my database.php file code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];

    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

    echo $firstName;

    echo $lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
return false;
```

to the end of your `click` handler. Otherwise, the default submit button action takes place, and the page is refreshed.

Also, remove the line:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Submit buttons aren't included when you call `.serialize()` on a form, they're only sent when the submit button is performing normal browser submission (in case there are multiple submit buttons, this allows the server to know which was used).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
                var srt = $("#input").serialize();
                // alert is working perfect
                alert(srt);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'database.php',
                    data: srt,
                    success: function(d) {
                        $("#someElement").html(d);
                    }
            return false;
});
```

Form default event will fire if you dont use return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below

```
$("#input").submit(function(event) {
    var srt = $("#input").serialize();
    // alert is working perfect
    alert(srt);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'database.php',
        data: srt,
        success: function(d) {
            $("#someElement").html(d);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as S Russell's answer?

Comment: Yes i do agreed but i posted before him :) and i was used submit event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of click event or the form will be processed using the default form action and your ajax call will never be complete.

```
$("#input").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    var srt = $("#input").serialize();
    // alert is working perfect
    alert(srt);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'database.php',
        data: srt,
        success: function(d) {
            $("#someElement").html(d);
        }
    });    
});
```